# What is the best way to declare a property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

We declare properties using the *@property* keyword and synthesize it in the implementation file. My question is,

What if I declare a property using the @property keyword and also declare a variable in the interface block with the same name? For example, consider the following code,

Interface:

```
@interface myClass : NSObject {

    NSString *myClass_name;  // LINE 1
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *myClass_name;  // LINE 2

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation myClass

@synthesize myClass_name  // LINE 3

@end
```

Declaring myClass_name in LINE 1 will make any problem? Like any reference problem or any unnecessary memory consumption problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in fact, declaring properties like that expects it. You could replace your declaration to:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSString *ivar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myClass_name;

@end
```

And then change your implementation to

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize myClass_name = ivar;

@end
```

(If you don't specify the = some_ivar, it will assume the ivar has the same name as the property.)

You always need to have the following lines:

- Declaration of the property (Line 2)
- Synthesization of the property (Line 3)

When you synthesize the property, if you do not specify which ivar to use (by using `=ivar` at the end), it will assume that there is an ivar with the same name as the property.

Comment: In this case, I don't need LINE 2?

Comment: @Justin Spahr-Summers: I need the LINE 2 or not? I really don't know. Pls tell me.

Comment: i Not get your question , according to me you declare proper just relase it in dealloc section

Comment: @Matt: Thanks man.. Your `@synthesize myClass_name = ivar` concept was really helpful to me.. I didn't know it before. Thanks for sharing..

Comment: Maybe you already have your answer, but to be clear about your question : you don't need LINE 1.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring properties and synthesizing it will not create any reference problem in your case.
Doing this will create accessor and setter methods for your instance variable in your class.
If the variable names in the property and the one declared in the class, then the xcode will refer both as a single variable.

Line 3 and Line 4 are must. Line 1 is optiona

Comment: Which line you mean by Line 4?

Comment: oh sorry my mistake,I meant Line 2 and Line 3 are must. Also I tried omitting Line 1 and running the code. In your case, does it result into any error if you omit line 1 ?

Comment: Can you pls change "Line 3 and Line 4" to "Line 2 and Line 3", in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got the following content from Apple's doc for [Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17). I am posting it here, so that it may be helpful for someone in future.

**Runtime Difference**

In general the behavior of properties is identical on all runtimes (see [Runtime Versions and Platforms](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH106) in [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048)). There is one key difference: the modern runtime supports instance variable synthesis whereas the legacy runtime does not.

For `@synthesize` to work in the legacy runtime, you must either provide an instance variable with the same name and compatible type of the property or specify another existing instance variable in the `@synthesize` statement. With the modern runtime, if you do not provide an instance variable, the compiler adds one for you. For example, given the following class declaration and implementation:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {

    float sameName;
    float otherName;
}

@property float sameName;
@property float differentName;
@property float noDeclaredIvar;

@end


@implementation MyClass

@synthesize sameName;
@synthesize differentName=otherName;
@synthesize noDeclaredIvar;

@end
```

the compiler for the legacy runtime would generate an error at `@synthesize noDeclaredIvar;` whereas the compiler for the modern runtime would add an instance variable to represent `noDeclaredIvar`.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the Object-oriented way:

DeclaringProperties.h

```
@interface DeclaringProperties : NSObject
// ivars and {} can be omitted

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSString *normal;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSString *alias;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSString *readonly;

- (id) initWithNormal:(NSString *)aNormal alias:(NSString *)alias;

@end
```

DeclaringProperties.m

```
#import "DeclaringProperties.h"

// private interface
@interface DeclaringProperties ()

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSString *readonly; // readwrite for self
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSString *private;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSString *retain;

@end

#pragma mark -

@implementation DeclaringProperties

@synthesize normal, alias = _alias, readonly, private, retain;

// You can not use "normal" here;
// But you can still use "alias", and it is highlighted in XCode!
- (id) initWithNormal:(NSString *)aNormal alias:(NSString *)alias {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.normal = aNormal;
        self.alias = alias;
        self.readonly = @"readonly";
        self.private = @"private";

        // allocated(copied) variable for retained(copied) property should be released or autoreleased
        NSString *alloc = [[NSString alloc] init];
        self.retain = alloc;
        [alloc release];
        // or
        self.retain = [[NSString alloc] init];
        [self.retain release];
        // or
        self.retain = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
        // I don't like ;)
        retain = [[NSString alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    self.normal = nil;
    self.alias = nil;
    self.readonly = nil;
    self.private = nil;
    self.retain = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```